# Keeping form fields after FPDF/FPDI generation

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdf, fpdi

I've scoured the forums/web for this answer, but I've failed to come up with a solution.

I have a PHP based form that inputs form data onto a PDF generated by FPDF/FPDI (utilizing a pre-made template). That, in and of itself, is working just fine.

I have one version that is a simple quote; the user can input their email without adding in personal information if they're not ready to move forward. A PDF is created with their quote info. The question has come up on whether or not this generated PDF can have form input fields and a send button, that way the client can send along their newly completed form with their quote information.

Does anyone know of a utility out there that can generate a functional PDF with input fields/send button and also input data from a PHP form?

Whoever can help will be this girl's hero. I may even send you cookies.

Comment: why pdf? why not a regular html form?

Comment: The client has requested to have generated PDFs. They think it's better for their marketing to have something tangible.

Comment: ...Either way, I need this to work on a PDF.